# I can't find my mw2 multiplayer progress data on my xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I have a Xbox 360 but I cannot find my Modern Warfare 2 multiplayer data. I have searched on my Memory and on my USB but still cannot find it.

Comment: I don't know definitively, but I'm pretty sure the multiplayer data isn't stored locally, and is on their servers.

Comment: I want a copy to my xbox?

Answer (score 1):

If this is for modifications (such as all gun unlocks, prestige edits etc) , you are only able to edit your Offline Data.